# Different return values of the sum of a row with imputed values using 'complete' (mice) and 'update' (survey)

Tags: r, survey, imputation, r-mice

I need to calculate the sum of some variables with imputed values. I did this with `complete` --> `as.mids` --> `with` --> `do.call`

I needed to do the same thing but in a survey context. Therefore, I did: `update` --> `with` --> `MIcombine`

The means of the variables calculated both ways do not match. Which one is correct?

You may check this different behavior in this toy database:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(mice)
library(mitools)
library(survey)

mydata <- structure(list(dis1 = c(NA, NA, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), 
                         dis2 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), 
                         dis3 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
                         sex = c(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0),
                         clus = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)), 
                    row.names = c(NA, 10L), 
                    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame") )

imp <- mice::mice(mydata, m = 5, seed = 237856)

# calculating numenf with mice::complete 
long <- mice::complete(imp, action = "long", include = TRUE)
long$numenf <- long$dis1 + long$dis2 + long$dis3
imp2 <- mice::as.mids(long)
res <- with(imp2, mean(numenf))
do.call(mean, res$analyses) # mean = 2.1

#calculating numenf with update (from survey)
imp1 <- mice::complete(imp)
imp2 <- mice::complete(imp, 2)
imp3 <- mice::complete(imp, 3)
imp4 <- mice::complete(imp, 4)
imp5 <- mice::complete(imp, 5)
listimp <- mitools::imputationList(list(imp1, imp2, imp3, imp4, imp5))                                             
clus <- survey::svydesign(id = ~clus, data = listimp)
clus <- stats::update(clus, numenf = dis1 + dis2 + dis3)
res <- with(clus, survey::svymean(~numenf))
summary(mitools::MIcombine(res)) # mean = 1.98
```

Comment: Hi, I tried modifying your post to include all the necessary information, but I cannot seem to replicate it. With `mice::complete` I get 1.9 (instead of 2.1), and the survey route gives me an error. Can you confirm that it works and that the new code is correct? Otherwise, can you adapt where necessary? After that I'll have a look.

Comment: Thank your for your interest, @slamballais. Yes, I've just tried the syntax and obtained the same result with complete. For the record, I've checked by hand that the correct result is 1.98, the one provided by survey/update. This is the mean of the means of numenf in the 5 imputed databases. I cannot understand how mice/complete gets 2.1 (at least in my computer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

Replace `do.call(mean, res$analyses)` with `mean(unlist(res$analyses))`.

---

**Rationale**

In the first code snippet, `res$analyses` is a `list`. When entering it into `do.call`, you are essentially calling:

```r
mean(res$analyses[1], res$analyses[2], res$analyses[3], res$analyses[4], res$analyses[5])
```

`mean` takes the average of a `vector` in its first argument. The other arguments are not used properly (see `?mean`). Hence, you're just getting `2.1` back, since that is the (mean of the) value of first analysis.

---

We can make a `vector` out of the `list` by using `unlist(res$analyses)`. Then, we can just feed it to `mean` as an argument:

```r
mean(unlist(res$analyses))
```

Comment: Thank you again. Now I get the same (and correct) result with both approaches. Just to make your answer absolutely precise, I was getting 2.1 (not 1.9) because this is the mean of the first element of res$analyses

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure why, but I'm getting different average numbers than you. Probably some seed procedural difference. I'll adapt the answer :)